# Make use of a variable value of a servlet from another servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I have two servlets. A and B. I need to make use of the variable from servlet A in servlet B say servlet A has String name="geoinformatics." I need to make use of this in Servlet B. On my research i was asked to use 1)requestDispatcher 2)set session attribute and receive it from B.
3)use servletContext to set and get the attribute. i tried but in vain Any help on this would be appreciated.Please provide some examples to make it clear.thanks

```
Servlet A :
String name="geoinformatics";
ServletContext context=getServletContext();
context.setAttribute("action",name);

Servlet B :
ServletContext context=getServletContext();
String type=(String)context.getAttribute("action");
```

Comment: You need to show code indicating what you've tried for anybody to be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the attribute with the request instead of the context.

`req.setAttribute (key, value);`

req.getAttribute (key);